# Что прочитать дляя подготовки к экзамену?

Tags: литература, образование

Здравствуйте. Собираюсь поступать на Факультет русской филологии и документоведения Направление «Педагогическое образование» 
профиль «Русский язык» Но т.к. я мало что читал из русской литературы... Да и в грамматике не силён, но желание учиться огромное! Подскажите литературу, которую точно стоит прочитать.  Вступительные экзамены будут по: обществознание, 
литература, 
русский язык

Answer (score 1):

Для начала - всего Розенталя )))